# Android image decoding massive memory consumption

Tags: android, performance, android-bitmap

I wanted to compress/re-scale an image before uploading. Here is the code that I use for compression. It works well for very large images, but this [particular image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3otzrcrbdumvnb/190_bottom_superhires.jpg?dl=1) ate up a [huge amount of RAM](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgmuenb531t04tj/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-11%20at%206.54.24%20pm%20%282%29.png?dl=0). I have linked the necessary images. Here is the code that I use.

I had to forcefully call System.gc() to release the overly used memory.

```
public static File compressImage(File image) throws IOException {

        // Decode just the boundaries
        final BitmapFactory.Options mBitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        mBitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(image);
        final Bitmap temporary = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream, null, mBitmapOptions);
        if (temporary != null)
            temporary.recycle();

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = mBitmapOptions.outHeight;
        final int width = mBitmapOptions.outWidth;
        final int sideLength = 800;
        closeQuietly(fileInputStream);

        int reqHeight = height;
        int reqWidth = width;
        final int inDensity;
        final int inTargetDensity;

        if (height > width) {

            inDensity = height;
            inTargetDensity = reqHeight;
            if (height > sideLength) {

                reqHeight = sideLength;
                reqWidth = (width * sideLength) / height;
            }
        } else if (width > height) {

            inDensity = width;
            inTargetDensity = reqWidth;
            if (width > sideLength) {
                reqWidth = sideLength;
                reqHeight = (height * sideLength) / width;
            }
        } else {

            reqWidth = sideLength;
            reqHeight = sideLength;
            inDensity = height;
            inTargetDensity = reqHeight;
        }

        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth)
                inSampleSize *= 2;
        }

        //now go resize the image to the size you want
        mBitmapOptions.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
        mBitmapOptions.inDither = true;
        mBitmapOptions.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = true;
        mBitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        mBitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        mBitmapOptions.inScaled = true;
        mBitmapOptions.inDensity = inDensity;
        mBitmapOptions.inTargetDensity = inTargetDensity * mBitmapOptions.inSampleSize;

        final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("compressed_profile_photo", null);
        final FileInputStream fInputStream = new FileInputStream(image);
        final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);

        // will load & resize the image to be 1/inSampleSize dimensions
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fInputStream, null, mBitmapOptions);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        bitmap.recycle();
        closeQuietly(fInputStream, fileOutputStream);

        //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
        image.delete();
        return tempFile;
    }
```

Comment: The image you linked is 4208x5198, and will take 4208*5198*2 = 41.7MB in RGB_565 format for the pixel data alone. Your memory consumption chart appears to show roughly that, so you're getting a full-size bitmap. Calling `System.gc()` may release the memory sooner, but there is little value in calling it manually, as it will be discarded the next time the GC feels it needs to (unless you have some sort of real-time requirement and need to manage the timing of the GC).

Comment: I tried an image which is twice the resolution of the image I linked, the memory consumption didn't spike at all. Hardly 5-10 mbs extra.

Comment: You can use the DDMS allocation tracker  (https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/allocation-tracker/index.html) to see exactly what is being allocated, and from where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a silly mistake in this part :

```
if (height > width) {

            inDensity = height;
            inTargetDensity = reqHeight;
            if (height > sideLength) {

                reqHeight = sideLength;
                reqWidth = (width * sideLength) / height;
            }
        } else if (width > height) {

            inDensity = width;
            inTargetDensity = reqWidth;
            if (width > sideLength) {
                reqWidth = sideLength;
                reqHeight = (height * sideLength) / width;
            }
        }
```

it should be this :

```
if (height > width) {

            if (height > sideLength) {

                reqHeight = sideLength;
                reqWidth = (width * sideLength) / height;
            }
            inDensity = height;
            inTargetDensity = reqHeight;

        } else if (width > height) {

            if (width > sideLength) {
                reqWidth = sideLength;
                reqHeight = (height * sideLength) / width;
            }
            inDensity = width;
            inTargetDensity = reqWidth;

        }
```

Because of this resize was not even happening !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just follow [the tip of the Official Training](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto)?

```
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```